# "Phantom applications" when running a Service Fabric App in Refresh Application Mode

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-service-fabric

We are using Refresh Application mode to develop the application locally. But after a few deploys with Debug -> Start Debugging (F5) we start getting warnings for locked files from the service fabric processes.

We've experienced this issue on a lot of development machines.

We are developing on machines running Windows 10

So far we've discovered that the Visual Studio unregistered the application from the cluster but the processes for the services are still running in the background.

Even if we go ahead and kill them the Fabric cluster runs them again even if there is no application registered in the cluster.

In order to get rid of these process we have to stop the cluster and run it again or reset it as a whole.

The warnings that Visual Studio produces

```sh
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4194,5): warning MSB3026: Could not copy "obj\Debug\net461\win7-x64\ServiceName.exe" to "bin\Debug\net461\win7-x64\ServiceName.exe". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\net461\win7-x64\ServiceName.exe' because it is being used by another process. The file is locked by: "ServiceName (14800)"
```

Comment: Maybe your service process can't exit properly? Do you have communication listeners that don't close, or a `RunAsync` that doesn't exit?

Comment: @LoekD There is no issue with the exit of the services. We can stop/start/scale them without any issues. The issue is that there are processes for services that don't exist. Visual Studio cleans solution and removes the services and the app but in the task manager you can still processes still running. Even if we kill them manually they get restarted almost instantly and there isn't even a registered application type at that moment.

Comment: @DobrinTinchev did I get you right. You are saying that when you have deleted the service and application from Service Fabric cluster (i.e. using Service Fabric Explorer) you are still seeing the running in Task Manager?

Comment: @OlegKarasik exactly and even if we kill them they start up again

Comment: @DobrinTinchev sorry for a silly question but does App disappears from Service Fabric Explorer? I am asking because I had the similar issue when SFE started to delete the App but the process never finished (so turns out the App was there in the "deleting" state).

Comment: @OlegKarasik yesthe App is gone from Service Fabric Explorer. I also tried limiting the amount of default services that are defined of the application manifest since we usually just work on 1-2 of the at a time. But still the same thing happens